# Существует ли способ вывода в iframe определенного блока (с стороннего сайта) у которого нет ID, а только класс?

Tags: html

Подскажите существует ли способ вывода в iframe определенной области стороннего сайта, при этом у блока который нужно отобразить в iframe нет ID, а есть только класс.

Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Стилями, вывод всей страницы, в блоке определенного размера, а iframe позиционировать внутри

```html
 <div class="iframe_block">
        <iframe src="https://ng.ru/" class="iframe_class" scrolling="no">Ваш браузер не поддерживает iframe!</iframe>
    </div>

    <style>
        .iframe_block {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 400px; /* Ширина окна */
            height: 300px; /* Высота окна */
        }
    
        .iframe_class {
            border: 0px;
            margin-left: -200px; /* Положение по горизонтали */
            margin-top: -33px; /* Положение по вертикали */
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
```

2. Скриптом

```html
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="https://ng.ru" width="500" height="350">Ваш браузер не поддерживает iframe!</iframe>
    
    <script>
        var get_iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_id");
        get_iframe.onload = function() {
            get_iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(20, 500);
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Второй вариант с скриптом почему то не срабатывает.

Comment: Первый вариант работает как надо, удается выбрать и отобразить нужную область стороннего сайта в фрейме. Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста, не появился ли способ вносить изменения в оформление загружаемого в iframe стороннего сайта? В частности задать значение `display:none` для некоторых элементов

Comment: стили менять нельзя из-за политики безопасности браузеров. А вообще, если есть возможность, то со сторонних сайтов данные лучше загружать через ajax, там можно менять оформление как угодно.